# Javascript: Constructing an Array inside an Array and Using console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, console.log

I'm in a JavaScript class, and have been given an assignment with the following instructions:

1. Create an array and assign this array to a variable named “presidents.”
2. Inside this array, create five objects, each with the following properties:

   - firstName
   - lastName
   - termLength
   - party
   - yearsOfPresidency
3. Fill in the appropriate information for each of
   the five the most recent US presidents.
4. Use console.log(), the presidents variable, and array notation to log out the first and last name of the third president (this should log out “Bill     Clinton”).

This is what I have so far:

```js
var presidents: [{
  firstName: 'Barak',
  lastName: 'Obama',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Democratic',
  yearsOfPresidency: '2009-Present'
}, {
  firstName: 'George W.',
  lastName: 'Bush',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Republican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '2001-2009'
}, {
  firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Clinton',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Democratic',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1993-2001'
}, {
  firstName: 'George H. W.',
  lastName: 'Bush',
  termLength: '4 years',
  party: 'Repuplican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1989-19934'
}, {
  firstName: 'Ronald',
  lastName: 'Reagan',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Republican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1981-1989'
}]

console.log(presidents(1, 1));
```

So, I know I'm probably not even close, and I've got an error (that I have no idea how to fix.)

My questions are:

1. How do I remove the error?
2. How do I properly get console.log to return "Bill Clinton?"
3. Do you have any other advice that I might be too ignorant to ask for?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Change `var presidents: [` to `var presidents = [`.

Comment: First you should make `var presidents = [{...` and then to access array items you use bracket notation. Like presidents[2] (which is the one at index position 2 and the third in the array since indices start at 0

Comment: 2. `console.log(presidents[2]['firstName'] + ' ' + presidents[2]['lastName']);`

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Comment: This is all about reading docs. First is essentially about defining a variable and second about using arrays. Hence the downvote - no apparent research  efforts.

Comment: I presume by what they call "array notation" (a term that should not be used for confusion with literals) they mean *bracket notation* for property access that is necessary to access the array elements by index.

Comment: I have watched my instructor's recorded classes, watched two full-lenght Lynda.com courses, referred to JavaScript: A Beginner's Guide, and much more. Believe me, I've conducted a ton of research. As I said, I'm new to JavaScript, so I need very specific instructions, like the very helpful suggestions provided by janje. (Thank you sooo much!)

Comment: So, assuming that I have in index.html file with the js file correctly referenced, should "Bill Clinton" be visible on the web page?

Comment: Does your class have a textbook? Does it have a chapter on arrays and objects? Does it explain how to access an element of an array? I don't understand why you're taking the class if you're not going to bother studying the material. I doubt they gave the assignment without first teaching the basics you need to do it.

Comment: (I know this is a very newbie question, and I apologize if it seems to deserve a "downvote." I'm definitely hoping for the gracious assistance of people much more advanced than me. Our class has only recently learned terms like "array," and I've never heard the terms "index" or "literals" before. When the syntax, terminology, software, and concepts are all new, it doesn't help a whole lot to keep reading.)

Comment: Awww. Ouch. Please, if you can't help or don't want to, don't post a comment. I'd rather not take the time to explain the whole background of the class, and I'd really rather not publicly disparage the way the class is being taught. If you think I'm a lazy idiot, you don't have to participate in this discussion.

Comment: I'm sorry! I didn't realize that this is not a forum for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the 3rd item in the array with presidents[2]
and then access any of the properties inside by using presidents[2].propertyname

in your example presidents[2].firstName, presidents[2].lastName

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `var presidents :` and is `var presidents =`.

To console log *Bill Clinton* you need to do this:

```
const bill = presidents[2];
console.log(bill.firstName+" "+bill.lastName);
```

All the snippet:

```js
var presidents = [{
  firstName: 'Barak',
  lastName: 'Obama',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Democratic',
  yearsOfPresidency: '2009-Present'
}, {
  firstName: 'George W.',
  lastName: 'Bush',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Republican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '2001-2009'
}, {
  firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Clinton',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Democratic',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1993-2001'
}, {
  firstName: 'George H. W.',
  lastName: 'Bush',
  termLength: '4 years',
  party: 'Repuplican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1989-19934'
}, {
  firstName: 'Ronald',
  lastName: 'Reagan',
  termLength: '8 years',
  party: 'Republican',
  yearsOfPresidency: '1981-1989'
}]


const bill = presidents[2];
console.log(bill.firstName + " " + bill.lastName);
```